# Request Body is always empty

Tags: go, postman, server-side

I am sending a POST request using POSTMAN to a route in my `localhost`.

[image]

The route has been perfectly defined in my `main.go` file. Moreover, it also gets triggered by sending the post request.

However, when I try to print the body, it always seems to be empty.

I tried to replicated the issue with the code below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "path"
    "strings"
)

func MeetingOperations(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        reqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "%+v", string(reqBody))
        fmt.Println(string(reqBody))
        fmt.Println("SCHEDULE MEETING ROUTE")
}

func handleRequests() {
    http.HandleFunc("/meetings/", MeetingOperations)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000", nil))
}

func main() {
    handleRequests()
}
```

Yet the body is logged as empty in the console.

[image]

I have tried sending a request using curl with no success. I also tried creating an HTML template form and submitting it with no luck.

Any sort of help or explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: A GET request does not have a body. Use POST/PUT

Comment: The screenshot you added is `GET` request and not POST request. Also, always check errors (reqBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body))

Comment: Sorry let me update that

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to check errors and why?

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing slash in your route definition, but in your Postman request its missing.  If you use a library, you can typically handle this case.